# Visualising MPEG TS informations (PMT, PAT) with wireshark

Tags: mpeg

I captured a multicast MPEG stream (scrambled) transported over UDP, using a bridge between a set-top-box and the router.

I would like to extract these informations : PMT, Audio tracks PIDS, video track PID, subtitle PIDs ..etc

When I apply the MP2T dissector, I can see some "PID" informations on my capture but they don't correspond to what I'm looking for (the actual PIDs in the stream). It's like I'm missing a level of information with this filter.
How can I achieve that using Wireshark ? My goal is to find a method to see this (MPEG stream tracks infos) **using only wireshark**. I went to through several tutorials but they all require to extract the TS and to analyze with another tool.

Thanks

Comment: This site is about video *production* whereas your question is more about a network tool. Therefore it is off-topic here. I think your question could be a better fit for https://superuser.com/

Comment: I disagree that this is definitively off-topic. It falls into the engineering grey area of questions that have been answered here before. However, the question may still not get an answer here, possibly because it isn't possible to do what @pacman29 is asking for in Wireshark alone.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use ffprobe ?

see the   `Stream #0:0[0x100]` the hex number in the brackets is the pid.

```
  Input #0, mpegts, from 'video_109936.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:06.03, start: 74973.058900, bitrate: 2252 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
    Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive), 848x480, Closed Captions, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x101]: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Stream #0:2[0x102]: Data: timed_id3 (ID3  / 0x20334449)
```